# Workflow for multiple (>5) contributors to one question

Tags: list

I have a number, lets say 100 questions which will be hosted within a list. Each question could have a single expert identified to answer it, some may have more (usually 2-3 max).

What I'd like to do is have each of them contribute their response, which I can then review and combine into a single response which will then go to another party for checking (or be kicked back to the contributors for further work).

I'm struggling to see if it's possible to have >1 person feed a response into a single question/list entry.

Anyone able to give pointers?

Answer (score 0):

If the amount of expert feedback is finite then you could have i.e. three feedback columns and three expert columns.

These can be used to send the emails and store the responses.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the replies so far.  Ideally I'd like to be able to name the contributors and then have it generate a field each, which I can then manually review and consolidate. As across the many questions I'll have different numbers of experts, it would make a basic list long and messy :( with redundant fields where a question only needs input from one person

Answer (score 0):

Add a column 'Review Comments' with type 'Multiple lines of text' (set the option 'Append Changes to Existing Text' to 'Yes'). You need to enable versioning for this list otherwise this field will only capture the last comment.

Comment: How will this work if he wants to review it to contributors?

Comment: Each contributor can update the list item with their comments! The new comments will get appended to previous comments but will show composite information of who, when and what comments! It is very easy to try and will be more clear when you try it!

Comment: I'm aware of it but i think what he's asking is different. He wants contributors to review the comments they entered, not add more comments on top of their comments.

Comment: "I'm struggling to see if it's possible to have >1 person feed a response into a single question/list entry." - I took this as the problem he is facing and contributors are the ones who add comments. Hopefully Gords will respond and provide clarification. Thanks for explaining yourself.